# Pandas apply giving float error when operation is performed on string

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe with a column `test` that contains test names, which I am using that to extract some information about what grade a test was written. Because I know that the string used for the test name always has the grade in it as the next digit after the date I have been extracting that data using this line of code:

```
df['Grade'] = df['test'].apply(lambda x: str(list(filter(str.isdigit, x[10:]))[0]))
```

This line, however, gives a `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`. Now, I should note that before I ran this, I did a check with `df.dtypes` and the column `test` was listed as `object`. That makes sense, as the string for the test names are something like `2015-2016_math_grade_7`, so there is no way it could be seen as a float by Pandas.

I have checked, and test names are the only data in that column, so I have no idea why I am getting this type error. No matter what I change the code to, I get this error because I need to perform a string operation after `x[:10]`. (I have used `df['Grade'] = df['test'].apply(lambda x: str(re.sub("\D", "", str(x[:10]))))`)

I should also note, that I have used this code before and it worked perfectly, but for some reason on this data set it seems to fail, if that helps.

Comment: Try `df['test'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: str(list(filter(str.isdigit, x[10:]))[0]))`

Comment: Hard for us to fix your code without a testable example, but I would recommend (at least temporarily) converting your `apply` to a `for-loop`, that way you can check the input and `try` `except` on the errors so you can find the problem

Comment: Perhaps you have a blank in your dataset, which would be represented as a nan (of type float)